# FPDI with FPDF installation

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

I have installed and created a few PDF documents with FPDF.
I currently need to insert a large number of small pdf graphs (created with R) at the end of a pdf being created with FPDF. I've spent a lot of time trying to get FPDI installed and running, but with little success. I've gone over the documentation many times and have searched for a demo that would work to help me figure things out. I'm using PHP 7 on a Windows 2019 Server and prototyping with PHP 7 on a Linux box.
So if someone can just give me the simple detailed steps and possibly a demo to get FPDI running, I'd appreciate the help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? We have several [demos](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/) including the complete code online. Also post the error messages you got.

Comment: After finally figuring out how to get to the Apache log file to trace down the 500 error, I found that I had a typo in the path to the src folder (rookie mistake). I did get the demo to run on the Windows server, The problem with the Linux box was PHP v5.x. Got that updated and all is well with running FPDI. I still appreciate you at least taking a look at my post.